# ReduxForm: using formValueSelector within a FieldArray for conditional fields doesn't render immediately

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

This *sort of* works, except additional block doesn't show up when I make a service_type radio selection, it only pops up/re-renders if I complete an additional action, like adding or removing a service block or changing another field.

```
    import './Register.scss';
    import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { Field, reduxForm, FieldArray, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form';
    import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
    import { RadioButton } from 'material-ui/RadioButton'
    import {
      TextField,
      SelectField,
      TimePicker,
      RadioButtonGroup
    } from 'redux-form-material-ui';
    import validate from './validate';

    class OnboardPageThree extends Component {
      static propTypes = {
        handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        previousPage: PropTypes.func.isRequired
      }

      constructor(props, context) {
            super(props, context);
        }

      renderGroups = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error } }) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {fields.map((service, index) =>
              <div className="service-type-group" key={index}>
                <h4>{index} Service</h4>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="remove-button"
                  onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}>Remove
                </button>
                <div className="field-group half">
                  <Field
                    name={`${service}.service_type`}
                    component={RadioButtonGroup}
                    floatingLabelText="Service type"
                    className="textfield">
                    <RadioButton value="first_come_first_serve" label="First-come first-served"/>
                    <RadioButton value="appointments" label="Appointment"/>
                  </Field>
                </div>
                {/* Sort of works except doesn't populate until forced re-render by adding another to array or updating a previous field */}
                {typeof this.props.services[index].service_type != undefined && this.props.services[index].service_type == "first_come_first_serve" ? <div className="fieldset">
                  <p className="label">Timeslot capacity and length when creating a first-come-first-served (line-based) service blocks</p>
                  <div className="field-group sentence-inline">
                    <Field
                      name={`${service}.max_people`}
                      type="number"
                      component={TextField}
                      label="Number of people per timeslot"
                      className="textfield"
                    />
                    <p>people are allowed every</p>
                    <Field
                      name={`${service}.time_interval`}
                      component={SelectField}
                      className="textfield">
                      <MenuItem value="5" primaryText="5 minutes" />
                      <MenuItem value="10" primaryText="10 minutes" />
                      <MenuItem value="15" primaryText="15 minutes" />
                      <MenuItem value="30" primaryText="30 minutes" />
                      <MenuItem value="60" primaryText="60 minutes" />
                      <MenuItem value="all_day" primaryText="All day" />
                    </Field>
                    <p>.</p>
                  </div>
                </div> : null}
              </div>
            )}
            <button
              type="button"
              className="action-button"
              onClick={() => fields.push({})}>Add Service
            </button>
            {touched && error && <span className="error-message">{error}</span>}
          </div>
        );
      }

      render() {
        const { handleSubmit, previousPage } = this.props;

        return (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h2>When do you provide service?</h2>
            <FieldArray name="service_options" component={this.renderGroups} />
            <div className="justify-flex-wrapper service-actions">
              <button type="button" className="back-button" onClick={previousPage}>Back</button>
              <button type="submit" className="action-button">Next</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        );
      }
    }

    OnboardPageThree = reduxForm({
      form: 'onboarding',
      destroyOnUnmount: false,
      validate
    })(OnboardPageThree)

    const selector = formValueSelector('onboarding');
    OnboardPageThree = connect(
      (state) => {
        const services = selector(state, 'service_options');
        return {
          services
        };
      }
    )(OnboardPageThree);

    export default OnboardPageThree;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that is true. The `FieldArray` does not re-render on the change of any of its items (that would be *really* bad for large arrays), only on size changes.

You will have to create a separate connected component for your array items. I have worked up [a working demo here](https://gist.github.com/erikras/43a60a4adade000254b3f284339d7548).

Comment: You're a saint and makes tee-total sense. Thank you so very kindly!

Comment: @Erik R. , I have a FieldArray , where I need to do some calculation like when I fill in 2 text boxes , it should validate both the values for numbers and  substract both numbers.Then populate the result in third text box. Can you please let me know how can we do that and give any pointers/link on the same. Thank you.